# what is wrong with me ? when I run server

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Syntax Error: Error: Failed to load plugin '@typescript-eslint' declared in 'package.json » @vue/eslint-config-typescript/recommended » ./index.js': Cannot find module '@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to install the typescript es-lint module, you can do that by using the yarn or npm commands below:

```
$ yarn add -D typescript @typescript-eslint/parser
$ npm i --save-dev typescript @typescript-eslint/parser
```